# Sublime Text 2: How do I change the color that the row number is highlighted?

Tags: sublimetext

As the subject says, I want to change to something other than the very light grey as shown below (line 319).  I have a hard time seeing that, especially when doing a 'find in files' command.

[image]

Comment: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5630#p26629

Answer (score 168, accepted):

The easy way: Pick an alternative Color Scheme:

**Preferences > Color Scheme > ...pick one**

The more complicated way: Edit the current color scheme file:

**Preferences > Browse Packages > Color Scheme - Default > ... edit the Color Scheme file you are using:**

Looking at the structure of the XML, drill down into `dict > settings > settings > dict >`

Look for the key (or add it if it's missing): `lineHighlight`. Add a string with an `#RRGGBB` or `#RRGGBBAA` format.

Comment: This [https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/wiki/Theme-customisation] makes it seem like there is a better way that doesn't involve editing the original them file. Alas I can't get it to work to override tmTheme files (yet) :-(

Comment: If you don't want to edit an original theme, then just make a copy of it, name it whatever, and then edit that.

Comment: if you seek cusotmization, see answer below with link to color scheme web editor

Comment: What does `dict > settings > settings > dict >` refer to?

Comment: @steel Sorry, that is mean't to indicate the XML structure. So look for `<dict>`, then among it's children look for `<settings>`, then `<settings>`, then `<dict>`.

Answer (score 14):

On windows 7, find

```
C:\Users\Simion\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Color Scheme - Default
```

Find your color scheme file, open it, and find `lineHighlight`.
Ex:

```
<key>lineHighlight</key>
<string>#ccc</string>
```

replace `#ccc` with your preferred background color.

Comment: Thanks for this. On mac, it is in your Users/Yourname/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Color Scheme - Default/nameofcolorscheme.tmTheme

Answer (score 12):

[tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com) seems pretty nice.

On the mac, the default theme files are in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/Color\ Scheme\ -\ Default`

On Win7, the default theme files are in `%appdata%\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Color Scheme - Default`

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no way of confirming the Win7 path that Ryan added to my answer, as I only have a mac.  @RyanB, may I suggest adding such things as comments?

Comment: Linux: w/o slashing: `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Color Scheme - Default` with slashing: `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Color\ Scheme\ -\ Default/`. You can edit your post if you wish @JaredBeck

Comment: On OSX simply drop the file you download from the editor into `~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/` and it will show up in your menu. (no need to put it in the default dir). Note this also works for ST3 (just change the 2 to a 3 above).

Comment: Pretty handy, i like it! Any way to edit the code on the app so you can see what something like `var blob` would look like with that config?

Comment: Nvm, just found the button at the bottom of the page to change language.

Answer (score 6):

For Sublime Text 3, all I had to do was add `"highlight_line": true` to my user settings file: Preferences -> Settings - User. It was only once that preference was set that all the color scheme `lineHighlight` settings took effect.

Hopefully this will save someone else some of this same flailing about.

Comment: op wants to *change the highlight color*

Answer (score 5):

### This post is for Sublime 3.

I just installed Sublime 3, the 64 bit version, on Ubuntu 14.04.
I can't tell the difference between this version and Sublime 2 as far as user interface.
The reason I didn't go with Sublime 2 is that it gives an annoying "GLib critical" error messages.

Anyways - previous posts mentioned the file
`/sublime_text_3/Packages/Color\ Scheme\ -\ Default.sublime-package`

I wanted to give two tips here with respect to this file in Sublime 3:

1. You can edit it with pico and use `^W` to search the theme name. The first search
   result will bring you to an XML style entry where you can change the values. Make a copy
   before you experiment.
2. If you choose the theme in the sublime menu (under Preferences/Color Scheme) before you change this file, then *the changes will be cached* and your change will not take effect. So delete the cached version and restart sublime for the changes to take effect. The cached version is at
   `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Cache/Color Scheme - Default/`

Answer (score 2):

If you have [SublimeLinter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/installation.html) installed, your theme (at least it ST3) may end up in .../Packages/User/SublimeLinter/[ your-chosen-theme ]

As mentioned above - find the nested 'settings' dict and edit or add the 'lineHighlight' entry with your desired `#RRGGBB` or `#RRGGBBAA`.  I like `#0000AA99` when on a black(ish) background.

Handy tool if you do not know your color combinations: [RGBtoHEX](http://www.rgbtohex.net/) and [HEXtoRGB](http://www.rgbtohex.net/hextorgb/)