# Changing syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

How can I change the highlight setting of Sublime Text 2, so that the text between quotes doesn't get pink like that and almost hurts my eyes?

**EDIT:** forgot to mention, this is happening in LaTeX files and I am using theme Monokai (if that matters, not really sure).

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This might be what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11656100/1624921

Comment: What syntax are you using? The highlighting has to do with the scope that is applied to that region. I don't think you want to modify the color scheme file, but rather the tmLanguage file. More details will make it easier to help though :)

Comment: @skuroda You're so right. Forgot to add those details in the question. Just edited it now. Please take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it was LaTeX, but wanted to make sure. So, there are 2 possible fixes for this.

The first is to define quotes properly. That is, using `"` renders incorrectly. I'll be honest, I didn't know about that until I came across the following post ([link](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/02/15/top-latex-mistakes/)). I think this would be the correct thing to do.

The second method is to modify the tmLanguage file. The following scope is being applied to that string `invalid.illegal.string.quoted.double.latex`. You can remove the associated pattern from the tmLanguage file, and it should stop that highlight from occurring. If you want to take this route, let me know and I can provide some additional instructions on how to do it.

Comment: What a strange behavior for the " (double quotes). I am changing as suggested in the link you provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(I encountered the similar problem and search through several StackOverflow Q&A pages but the answers seems not to satisfied my needs). Well, a lot of people praise JSON type configuration file, about its flexibility or else... etc., but it's really a pain not to have a realtime GUI for style configurator (color scheme editing in the case of Sublime Text). How a new user know which option's **name(s)** should he tweak (just need one to two) between thousands of key-value pairs.

If you only need to change one or two things from a good default theme, you can use this website to create your own customized theme file. This guy really did a great job:
http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#/theme/Monokai