# Change color of caret in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Trying to configure a custom caret color..Here is what I have done so far but had no result in a successful output..

I have dowloaded the PackageResourceViewer and gone into my theme and changed the `<key>caret</key>` `<string>#F8F8F0</string>` to my own custom hex color.

Once this is done I then overwrite the current theme by choosing `save as` and restarting Sublime Text. After restart, I see no change made to the caret...Hmmm

I have also followed this post on 
[How do I edit the Solarized (Light) theme in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746993/how-do-i-edit-the-solarized-light-theme-in-sublime-text-3)

Any one have and suggestions? I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you "gone into your theme", did you *`open`* or *`extract`*?  By `open`, you are essentially viewing a read-only version, so saving it doesn't do anything really.

If you do `extract` it, try saving it into your `user` folder, then make sure you choose it via the preferences menu

Comment: Thax for your advise, In `extract` i select theme by pressing enter and nothing happens..How should I extract properly?

Comment: It copies the package to `Sublime Text 3\Packages\xxx`, then you have to use browse packages to find the file.