# How to change color of indent guide option in sublime text3?

Tags: sublimetext3, indentation

How to change indent guide color.

[image: indent guide color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the color scheme file for the color scheme you are using, and find `<key>activeGuide</key>` and/or `<key>guide</key>` and change the hex color value in the `<string>` node below it to the value of the color you desire. See [How do I edit the Solarized (Light) theme in Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746993/how-do-i-edit-the-solarized-light-theme-in-sublime-text-3) for details on how to make custom changes to color schemes.

Comment: this is solved my problem. thanks for your explanation and link.