# Highlighted indents in Sublime Text 3 like Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext3

I just discovered Sublime 3 and it truly is sublime (so much so that I will pay for it). So I am making the transition from notepad++... the issue I have at the moment is that Notepad++ has these fantastic indent highlights which are crucial for me to see where my parent elements are.

Here is the difference...

[image]

Regrettably Sublime does not highlight the indent on the currently selected indentation level... I can't believe this does not come default with the editor?

So my question is how do I enable the selected indent level to show up as say green.

Best,

Jethro

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952462/how-to-change-color-of-indent-guide-option-in-sublime-text3 and https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-config-it-to-highlight-current-indent-guide/7292/3

Comment: Stunning, I will accept this answer thanks!