# Sublime Text 2 color scheme - change object key color

Tags: sublimetext2, color-scheme

I'm wondering if there is a way to change the default color of object keys in Sublime Text 2.

I looked at this SO Q: [Sublime Text 2: How do I change the color that the row number is highlighted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807324/sublime-text-2-how-do-i-change-the-color-that-the-row-number-is-highlighted) and it didnt have quite what I was looking for; The [Tm-Theme Editor](http://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/) suggested is pretty awesome but doesnt seem to do what I want.

So, for example, with:

```
var foo = {
  key1 : 1,
  key2 : 2
}
```

By default `key1` and `key2` are white. I'd like to make them a separate color. I cant find the right tag in the `.thTheme` file I am currently using.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: javascript mostly. and thats where I'd like it to be applied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the standard JavaScript language definition that comes with Sublime does not include a scope for keys, so there's no way to color it differently. However, if you switch to using [`Java​Script​Next - ES6 Syntax`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/JavaScriptNext%20-%20ES6%20Syntax), which is a much more detailed language definition, you'll be able to use the `constant.other.object.key.js` scope to color the keys. Here is the difference between using standard JS:

[image: standard JavaScript]

and JavaScriptNext:

[image: JavaScriptNext]

Syntax highlighting is courtesy of my [`Neon Color Scheme`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), which has been designed to make as many languages as possible look as good as possible, using as many different scopes as possible. I've included several JavaScriptNext-specific items in it, including object names, Node keywords, constants, properties, and others. Please feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/issues/new) if you have any questions, concerns, feature requests, or other feedback. If you don't want to change over from your old color scheme, you can of course borrow whatever features you like from [the source](https://github.com/MattDMo/Neon-color-scheme/blob/master/Neon.tmTheme).

Hope this helps!